# Unable to display data with ngFor

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngfor

I am trying to fetch details of patient from a url containing json data using get method of angular.

My service class

**Patient Service class.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class PatientService{
    url="http://localhost:8080/rest/patientC";

    constructor(private http:Http){}

    getPatientWithObservale():Observable<patient[]>{
        return this.http.get(this.url)
                        .map(this.extractdata)
                        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }
private extractdata(res:Response){
        let body=res.json();
        console.log(body.data);
        return body.data || {};
    }
}

**Observable Component class.ts**

export class ObservableComponent implements OnInit{
    patients:patient[];
    errorMessage: string;
    patientName: string;
    patient=new patient();

    constructor(private patientService: PatientService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.fetchPatient();
    }

    fetchPatient():void{
        this.patientService.getPatientWithObservale()
                            .subscribe(patients=>this.patients = patients,
                            error=>this.errorMessage=error);

    }
}

**Observable component.html**

<h3>Patient Details with Observable </h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Disease</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let paty of patients">
        <td>{{paty.id}}</td>
        <td>{{paty.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{paty.lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{paty.gender}}</td>
        <td>{{paty.age}}</td>
        <td>{{paty.address}}</td>
        <td>{{paty.contactNo}}</td>
        <td>{{paty.disease}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Error:**

> ObservableComponent.html:13 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

It seems ngFor is unable to bind values. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's just 'patients' doesn't have array format expected by ngfor. check the http response format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states ngFor directive only works with iterables.

Your extractdata method might be returning an object

```
private extractdata(res:Response){
        let body=res.json();
        console.log(body.data);
        return body.data || {}; <--- returning object
    }
}
```

Change the return value to be array

```
private extractdata(res:Response){
        let body=res.json();
        console.log(body.data);
        return body.data || []; <-- change
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work but I got solution to this. Instead of returning 'body.data || {}; ' i changed it to 'body || {}'. I dont know why former didn't work but latter did.
Can anyone explain it?